# Fastest way to create a Shortcut ignoring drive mapping

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I create a shortcut to a network file using standard Windows Explorer "Right-click -> Create Shortcut", the shortcut link takes advantage of my network drive mapping, which substitutes a single letter and colon for a big chunk of the path.

This makes the shortcut harder to share with my co-workers, who don't have the same mapping.

**I want a shareable shortcut which links to the full path of the file, ignoring the mapping.**

My current solution involves opening another instance of Windows Explorer, starting at the network root, finding the same file without using the mapped drive, *then* creating the shortcut.

It's acceptable since I don't do it very often, but does anyone know a better way?

Comment: I don't have the time to look into it right now, but you should be able to accomplish this using PowerShell. The script could live in the `SendTo` folder. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/29933/get-the-current-unc-path-from-a-local-path-in-powershell) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell-or-cmd).

Answer (score 1):

You can always create it manually, if you know the name or the ip address of the share? You could do something like

```
\\servername\share
```

or

```
\\ip\share
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is to drag and drop using the Right-click on the mouse.  I actually WANT to use the mapping drive and am unable to, so my problem is your solution!

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work for me. When I drag and drop using the Right-click on the mouse, even to another folder, a different menu pops up, with, among other options, "Create shortcuts here". If I choose to create the shortcut, it uses the mapping drive. I'm getting the behaviour you'd like...