# Windows: Expand path of drive-mapped directory to full path

Tags: powershell, mapped-drive

I have some folders mapped as drives on my Win11 machine using the registry key

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
```

with string values such as

```
X:=\??\C:\some\folder
```

For the most part, this works flawlessly, and allows me to have several "drives" that share the space in a single disk partition.

Nevertheless, some programs (eg git) are able to "see" the actual drive location (for example, `X:\Foo` becomes `C:\some\folder\Foo`).

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that can be used to generate, for example, `C:\some\folder\Foo` when passed `X:\Foo`.

I have tried playing around with Get-Item, Split-Path, converting to a UNC (using the method outlined [here](https://superuser.com/questions/29933/get-the-current-unc-path-from-a-local-path-in-powershell)), but nothing seems to penetrate the veil of this method of mapping drive letters to a folder.

Am I missing something obvious?

==========================

Some more details, added 2024-01-16:

The volume-mapped folders are located within a drive that is mounted using VeraCrypt. In my case, the drive is D - strangely, it does not appear in the output from `Get-Volume`. Perhaps this is because of this note in the `Get-Volume` documentation: "Dynamic volumes are supported only by the following cmdlets: Repair-Volume (chkdsk), Optimize-Volume (defrag), and Format-Volume (format) on basic disks and storage spaces."

```
> Get-Volume
DriveLetter FriendlyName     FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------     -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C           Windows          NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     807.6 GB  952.8 GB
            Windows RE Tools NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     64.65 MB    814 MB
G           New Volume       NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    148.57 GB 909.15 GB
```

============================

Details of registry entries, added 2024-03-05

Here are the registry entries. There are three mapped drives (f:, p:, and q:) over-and-above the default entries in this registry key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### 2024-03-05

Use `Get-ItemProperty` on the registry path, store the result in a variable which will be a `PSObject` data type. Iterate through it using conditional logic and matching operators. Then, access the desired properties for each `PSObject`, parsing and reformatting accordingly.

Utilizing a logical approach similar to this should provide insight into how to incorporate or refine the process to better suit your requirements for obtaining the local file path.

### Registry Parse and String Build

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices";
$v = Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath;
foreach ($property in $v.PSObject.Properties) {
If ($property.Name -match ":"){$property.Value.Replace('\??\','')}
};
```

#### Output

**Note:** Based on the provided example registry settings.

```
D:\!Drives\F
D:\!Drives\P
D:\!Drives\Q
```

---

#### Original insufficient suggested solution detail

This potential solution essentially...

- Uses [`Get-Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to retrieve volume objects.
- Uses [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.4) to iterate over the objects, incorporating an [`If`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.4) statement including only those with a null "**Drive Letter**" and omits "**System Reserved**" labels.
- Creates a variable to store the iterated "**FileSystemLabel**" for subsequent use in a [`calculated property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#select-object).
- Passes the object through [`Get-Partition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-partition?view=windowsserver2022-ps) via the pipeline and leverages [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.4) with `calculated properties` to list the "**FileSystemLabel**" and "**AccessPath**".
- Lastly, it [splits](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) "**AccessPath**" within the `calculated property` with a comma as the delimiter, referencing only the first `[0]` index to achieve the desired output.

### PowerShell

```
Get-Volume | ForEach-Object {
    If (!($_.DriveLetter) -and 
        $_.FileSystemLabel -ne "System Reserved"){
        $fsl = $_.FileSystemLabel;
        $_ | Get-Partition | 
            Select-Object @{n="FileSystemLabel";e={$fsl}}, 
                @{n="AccessPaths";e={$_.AccessPaths.Split(',')[0]}}
    }
} | Sort-Object FileSystemLabel;
```

#### Output Example

```
FileSystemLabel AccessPaths
--------------- -----------
TempDB1         T:\TempDB1\
TempDB2         T:\TempDB2\
TempDB3         T:\TempDB3\
TempDB4         T:\TempDB4\
TempDB5         T:\TempDB5\
TempDB6         T:\TempDB6\
TempDB7         T:\TempDB7\
TempDB8         T:\TempDB8\
TempDBLog       T:\templog\
```

---

Comment: @vomit-it-chunky-mess-style : I think you have a typo in your code block. `{$_.DriveLetter -eq $null}` -- operator should be `-me` or (my preference) simply `{$_.DriveLetter}` .

Comment: @KeithMiller See screen shot of `get-volume` output here for example: https://i.imgur.com/WIvN1mt.png. Yeah, I think I could have used `If(!($_.DriveLetter))` too though, I do try to use that when I remember, creature of habit!

Comment: Sorry -- didn't have a mapped drive ATM and only thiing `-eq $null` was returning was `Windows RE tools` ...

Comment: vomit-it-chunky-mess-style : I probably read that and started playing interactively -- when I'm not well-acquaited with an object's propertes, I like to break down any pipelines in sample code to understand the flow...

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, the only output I am getting is `Windows RE Tools` with AccessPath ` \ `. But, after running just Get-Volume, I realized that a further complication is that the volume-mapped folders are within a drive mounted with VeraCrypt, and the volume (in my case, D) does not even appear in the Get-Volume output. I have updated my question with these additional details.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Unfortunately, `Get-PSDrive` makes no distinction between the physical and mapped drives - they all display as Provider FileSystem, with the root being the drive letter (rather than the mapped folder path). Maybe the solution is to scan the registry entries under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices` and extract the data from there.

Comment: Please send me a screen shot (you can blur anything sensitive) and I can get you some logic posted to do the extraction too. Keep me posted on some example and I will get you some logic to test. For me, that reg path is not applicable in the environment systems I currently maintain for mapped drives. Help me understand what data you have with a simple screen shot of that reg path detail, and I can definitely help with the extraction using PowerShell from the registry for your expected format. @EBlake

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I've added a screenshot of the relevant registry entries. I'm by no means an expert in PowerShell - I guess I'm stuck in the 80's when I got my start, so DOS batch files are more my thing ;)

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Eventually, I want to be able to run a script that issues a command like `git config --global --add safe.directory d:\!Drives\F\foo` where `foo` is a folder on the mapped F drive. `foo` would presumably be a command-line argument to the script, or perhaps in the absence of an argument, the script would default to using the directory/folder from which the script was executed.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle For interest, the issue I'm trying to semi-automate is discussed in this external link https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2023/Jan/05/Fix-that-damn-Git-Unsafe-Repository

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in one of the comments, I'm a novice PowerShell user, but I did manage to roll a solution that works for me. It is specific to my folder naming, but others should be able to adapt to their own needs. There are likely also more elegant solutions.

```
  # Get the contents of the HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
  # key into a text string
  $t = (Get-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices') | Out-String

  # Get the current working directory's drive letter and build the expected DOS Devices entry
  $d = $pwd.drive.name
  $s = '\??\D:\!Drives\' + $d

  # Find the position of that DOS Devices entry in the registry key
  $p = $t.IndexOf($s)

  # Check if the string exists
  if ($p -eq -1)
  {
     # Get out
     Write-Output 'The current drive is not mapped in DOS Devices - nothing to do!'
     exit
  }

  # Build git safe directory entry
  $sd = 'D:\!Drives\' + $d + $pwd.path.SubString(2)

  # Remove the entry, if it already exists - try with both forms of slashes
  Write-Output 'Remove any previous entry (try with both forms of slashes)'
  $e = 'git config --global --fixed-value --unset safe.directory ' + $sd
  $e
  iex $e
  $e = $e -Replace '\\','/'
  $e
  iex $e

  # Replace with new entry (replace back-slashes with forward slashes)
  Write-Output 'Add new entry'
  $e = 'git config --global --add safe.directory ' + $sd
  $e = $e -Replace '\\','/'
  $e
  iex $e
```